# Onde colocar comentários e javadoc ? Model ou Controller?

Tags: java, mvc, comentários, javadoc

Estou fazendo um programa MVC, porém na hora de descrever em um `javadoc` o que cada janela faz, eu fiquei em dúvida entre colocar esses comentários nas próprias `forms` (Model), ou nos `controllers` das respectivas janelas. Qual seria o mais correto ? Pois a `form` é a essência da janela, e o `controller` é quem faz a maioria das coisas ... Me ajudem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devemos dar pelo menos uma breve descrição de ambos, para que o programador que vá pegar os mesmos não tenha nem a possibilidade de não entender do que se trata.

```
/**
 * Modelo para criação e validação do Código de Barras da Caixa
 * 
 * @author João Victor B. Magalhães 
 * @since   0.1
 * @version 0.1
 * 
 */
public class CodigoDeBarrasCaixa implements CodigoDeBarrasBoleto {
    private String digitos;
    private BoletoBancario boleto;

    private static final int TIPO_DE_COBRANCA = 2;
    private static final int ID_EMISSOR_BOLETO = 4;
    private static final int TIPO_MOEDA = 9;
}
```

Não vejo necessidade em documentar os Getters e Setters, mas caso tenha algum método mais complexo ou um atributo de difícil entendimento é bom que documente também. No controlador a mesma coisa, dê uma descrição do que ele faz e caso ele tenha algum método fora do "comum" documente-o.
Se já for um programa que está distribuído em uma equipe coloque sempre o @since para a equipe saber quando você adicionou o método e o @version também.

Answer (score 1):

O javadoc não é a ferramenta mais indicada para descrever *como utilizar a interface gráfica* da aplicação, se é isso que você está tentando fazer. Ele serve para você descrever como utilizar as classes (e os métodos, consequentemente) do seu projeto.

No caso, se o que pretende fazer for realmente documentar as classes, você deve fazer isso tanto na model quanto na controller.

Comment: Qual seria a melhor forma de descrever a função de determinada classe e/ou método ? Os próprios comentários "normais" mesmo ?

Comment: @DanielSantos não não, no que se refere a classes e/ou métodos (que serão utilizados por outros desenvolvedores, ou mesmo você no futuro) é que você deve usar o javadoc. O que eu mencionei foi que se a ideia fosse documentar a utilização da interface gráfica por parte dos usuários aí sim o javadoc não seria o mais indicado.